# Is there a way to add a context for my methods (or exclude methods) in Swagger?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, swagger-2.0, nelmioapidocbundle

I have REST API, some methods are public, some methods are private. I want to generate two API docs, one for everybody and another one for private usage. I use https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle which uses https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php which uses Swagger 2.

A good example of the result is a context at JMS, where we can add different groups to our properties and hide them if we need to do them private.

I know that at Nelmio API doc we can add groups like at JMS, but we can't hide methods by that.

Is there any way on any level of these abstractions to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle can solve my problem itself by using area configuration like it is described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/areas.html

I've used the areas before but I have partly config in yaml and partly like annocations and also used basePath in my nelmioApiDoc config so all that worked together a bit different than I expected.